# Create synonym "kx" for tag "kdb"

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

End 2015, in an effort to gain traction outside of finance, [Kx Systems](https://kx.com/) has started to market its database [kdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kdb) as [kx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kx).

As both names are used interchangeably, would it be possible to create the tag-synonym 'kx' for 'kdb'.

I'm reaching out to Meta, as I've not been granted this privilege.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I honestly cannot see the need for such a synonym, as noone on main uses [kx] at all.
People are finding and using [kdb] as appropriate.

And if such a tag was to be introduced, I would prefer a slightly longer [kx-database].